# Why does this mock 'return' a Closure as opposed to the actual return value?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking, spock

I am mocking SearchableService in a Spock specification:

```
// In SearchControllerSpec:
def sControl    = mockFor(SearchableService)
sControl.demand.suggestQuery { Map m -> 'suggested query string' }
controller.searchableService    = sControl.createMock()
```

The code snippet under test looks as follows:

```
// In SearchController:
qSuggestion = searchableService.suggestQuery( query , allowSame:false)

// FAILS:
assert qSuggestion == 'suggested query string'

highlightedSuggestion = StringQueryUtils.highlightTermDiffs(query, qSuggestion)
```

The assertion fails - apparently due to the fact, that `qSuggestion` holds a closure as opposed to the defined string.

The final statement fails as highlightTermDiffs expects (String, String), but is getting (String, Closure).

**What's wrong here? How can I correct the error?**

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `suggestQuery(String, Map)` but you are mocking `suggestQuery(Map)`.  Try

```
sControl.demand.suggestQuery { String query, Map m -> 'suggested query string' }
```

Comment: Unsure why I missed commenting/accepting your answer. Currently http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPOCK-10 applies, so I'll check back when I'm able to test your suggestion.